# App screen turn white while receiving notification

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6

This is so weird, I've looked and nobody has the same problem as I was.

So, I noticed my app suddenly turn into white screen for few seconds when have incoming notification, this notification from other apps like facebook, whatsapp, etc. But it confuses me, why it effect my app when notification shown in the top screen for like 3 seconds, and my app turn into white except the notification.

This happened  on iPhone 5 (iOS6). never happen before on iOS5.

## EDIT

My app doesn't register notification, notification comes from other application, which nothing to do on my app. that is the strange one.

**By pulling down notification also my app turned into white.**

[image]

-<>-

Comment: there might be possibility... that you are trying to do something when notification comes... means changing color or you might had not set the clear color for the views..

Comment: Maybe you shuold look for your notification listener. iphone doesnt look for where does the notification is coming from, it just fires the notification listener..

Comment: nope, my app doesn't register notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I fixed my own problem. anyone face same problem like I was, can see this solution :

The problem is caused by **duplicate window in in App delegate xib**. which I might added accidentally into it, Silly of me.

[image]

Second window is just empty, unused. contain only white background - which is why this was shown when app received notification or by pulling down notification bar.

by removing it will solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I think you call a thread when notification is occurred, Or when notification appeared you call multiple thread with work on views push or pop or hevy load the data , please check on instrument and leak first and resolved the allocation problem and check with notification in second part.
let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: my app doesn't register notification. besides, I also noticed this happen also when I'm pulling down notification bar.